# Receiving bytes from a Bluetooth connection

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have an android application that connects to a Bluetooth module to send and receive data.
In the sending logic, its working fine and sending the data properly.

The variables:

```
  private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
  private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
  private static InputStream inputStream;
  private OutputStream outputStream;
```

Connecting to the module:

```
private void connectToDevice(String address) {
    UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    BluetoothSocket tmp;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    try {
      tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Snackbar.make(parentLayout, e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
          .setAction("IOException", null).show();
      return;
    }
    bluetoothDevice = device;
    bluetoothSocket = tmp;

    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
      bluetoothSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
      Snackbar.make(parentLayout, connectException.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
          .setAction("IOException", null).show();
      try {
        bluetoothSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException closeException) {
        Snackbar.make(parentLayout, closeException.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("IOException", null).show();
      }
      return;
    }

    try {
      outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
      inputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Snackbar.make(parentLayout, e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
          .setAction("IOException", null).show();

    }
  }
```

The sending logic:

```
public void SendMessage(byte Destination, byte Source, int Code, byte[] Payload) {
    if (Code > 255)
      Opt2_16_BIT_Code = "1";
    else
      Opt2_16_BIT_Code = "0";
    String optionsString = Opt8_Next_Message +
        Opt67_Response_Options +
        Opt5_Reserved +
        Opt34_Trace_Options +
        Opt2_16_BIT_Code +
        Opt1_Extended_Flag;
    byte Options = GetBytes(optionsString)[1];  // 00100000 // 0x20

    Message _Message = new Message(Destination, Source, Options, Code, Payload);
    AllMessage = _Message.GetAll();  // We get the whole buffer bytes to be sent to the Hexabitz modules.


    try {
      outputStream.write(AllMessage, 0, AllMessage.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Snackbar.make(parentLayout, e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
          .setAction("IOException", null).show();
    }

  }
```

All of the above is working fine, but when I come to receive data, the app don't respond at all even in the debug mode too.

This is the receive logic, am using the AsyncTask because in the normal mode it's freezing the main UI:

```
public static class ReceiveDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
      InputStream socketInputStream = inputStream;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
      int bytes;


      // Keep looping to listen for received messages
      while (true) {
        try {
          bytes = socketInputStream.read(buffer);            // Here its falling asleep and dosen't respond at all!
          String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
          testLBL.setText(readMessage);
          // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
          Log.i("logging", readMessage + "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Snackbar.make(parentLayout, e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
              .setAction("IOException", null).show();

          break;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Any suggestion or how can I receive the data, It's going to be a stream of bytes.

Comment: Where are you using "ReceiveDataTask" class? Are you sure you are executing it?
I think you should also check if the device is connected before running the task or it's going to fail (exactly in the line you mentioned it is failing).

Comment: Yes for sure I'am executing it while it's connected. @SoubhiM.Hadri